# Swift - adding xcodebuild arguments for Jazzy

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, xcodebuild, jazzy

I'm trying to use Jazzy to create docs for my xcode project. I'm able to run xcodebuild from my root folder successfully but only using the following arguments:

```
enter code here`xcodebuild -workspace myProj.xcworkspace -scheme "myProj (Staging)"
```

Without using these arguments I get a load of build errors.

So, when I run `jazzy` by itself in the command line from the root, obviously I run into problems because xcodebuild fails to run. So I believe I need to add these arguments to my jazzy command as well.

I've tried this using:

```
jazzy --xcodebuild-arguments -workspace myProj.xcworkspace -scheme "myProj (Staging)"
```

and also with:

```
jazzy --build-tool-arguments -workspace myProj.xcworkspace -scheme "myProj (Staging)"
```

But in both cases I run into this error:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/[user]/Desktop/Development/GitClones/myProj-ios/cheme (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Not sure where to go from here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on the same issue for a while, using these arguments fixed it:

```
jazzy \
  --clean \
  --xcodebuild-arguments -scheme,"myProj (Staging)" \
```